# How to remove the input element and wrap each clone element into li element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Using the following HTML content,

```
<div class="a_list"><iniput type="checkbox"><input/><p>Test Results from A column</p></div>
<div class="a_list"><iniput type="checkbox"><input/><p>Test Results from B column</p></div>
<div class="a_list"><iniput type="checkbox"><input/><p>Test Results from C column</p></div>
<di class="a_list"><iniput type="checkbox"><input/><p>Test Results from D column</p></div>
```

Try this and work but put all the checked items into one Li (list)

```
if($(".a_list input:checked").length)
{
    $(this).parent().clone().appendTo("#filterList ul").wrap("<li />");
} else {
    alert("Please make a selection");
}
```

I would like the following output

```
<ul id="#filterList">
    <li><p>Test Results from A column</p></li>
    <li><p>Test Results from B column</p></li>
    <li><p>Test Results from C column</p></li>
    <li><p>Test Results from D column</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why you're writing the input as iniput?? is it mistyping  or  what?

Comment: yes your input element is incorrect

Comment: oops, typing error, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

The following should grab each and `appendTo` independent of on another.

```
if($(".a_list input:checked").length)
{
  $(".a_list input:checked").each(function(){
     $(this).clone().appendTo("#filterList").wrap("<li\>");
  });
} else {
   alert("Please make a selection");
}
```